# Storing Authentication Token at application level which expires after certain time interval in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a Spring Rest application. From this application, I am giving call to few Rest APIs. All these APIs need an authentication token and there is a certain service that I call to get the latest token. This authentication token is valid for few hours and then again it expires and a fresh token is provided. I need to store this token in certain memory and use it for calling the APIs. If I get tokenExpiredException, I will be giving call to token generating method and retrieve the new token and store it in the memory again for use.
Please suggest the best place to store this token so that I can have it readily available for any number of user.

Comment: Never ever ever save token in memory.

Comment: So should I save it in DB? But if I save it in DB, won't it be an extra DB call everytime the method is called?